# Regex pattern for capital letters and numbers only, with possible 'List'

Tags: regex, numbers, capitalization

What is the regex to match words that have the pattern:

**Number or Capital in any order * 3 (+possible 'List' on the end)**

For example,

```
OP3
G6H
ZZAList
349
127List
```

are all valid, whereas

```
a3G
P-0List
HYiList
def
YHr
```

are all invalid.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can use the regex:

```
^[A-Z0-9]{3}(?:List)?$
```

Explanation:

```
^        : Start anchor
[A-Z0-9] : Char class to match any one of the uppercase letter or digit
{3}      : Quantifier for previous sub-regex 
(?:List) : A literal 'List' enclosed in non-capturing paranthesis
?        : To make the 'List' optional
$        : End anchor
```

[**See it**](http://www.rubular.com/r/VN5QMtQZ7y)

Comment: That works a treat, and thanks for including an explanation too, regex is starting to make more sense to me now. Though not by much... ;P

Answer (score 1):

A solution that works with diacritics on capital letters and with [Eastern Arabic numerals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Arabic_numerals):

```
^[[:upper:][:digit:]]{3}(?:List)?$
```

`[:upper:]` is a Posix class that matches all uppercase letters, including "É", "Ê", "Ç", "Ö" and so on. `[:digit:]` can also match numbers like ١٢٣.

[See it](https://rubular.com/r/Arl7rXcagWc2eV)