# Read row and search for only uppercase “words”

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I have a list or datatable that has several values.  In some way I have to scan the row and search for only capital letters (from 2 to 3) and then copy and paste into a new row.  It can be possible?

Some data:

```
T09 AT 98-67 Test
T19 AYR 98-67 Demo
```

EDIT: I managed to get just capital letter index, but what if I want only when the they are AT and not T.  I mean, 2 or 3 capital letter together?

```
for (int w = 0; w < s.Length; w++)
{
    if (Char.IsLetter(s[w]) && Char.IsUpper(s[w]))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("INDEX: {0}", w);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific; how do you connect to the database? Have you some code you can show for better illustration of the problem?

Comment: I did not say nothing about database, it is a datatable.

Comment: Is you problem with search base on the capital letter or some other parts?

Comment: Yes, the point is how to search, and them copy the matches into a new row.

Comment: So the datatable has 4 columns or just is each row just a string?

Comment: See duplicate. If your question is more specific than that, please edit it to show your current code and what exactly you need help with.

Comment: Is not clear enough, please clarify more

Comment: That is the data I have.  I know that is not something easy and that's the reason why I am in here looking for help.  I was thinking to use LINQ and RegExp.

Comment: you could try `^[^A-Z\s]+\.[^A-Z\s]+$`

Comment: @jimtollan thank you for the example, but how can I use it into LINQ or any other way to scan a row?

Comment: What happen if only number? assume as uppercase?

Comment: i'd suggest to start simply - i.e. pull the rows in 1st and makr the regex work as planned, then go for step 2. however, remember that linq works with iqueryable, therefore, there is no regex built into that, so you'll still have a major design issue to resolve with function vs performance

Comment: re capitals and numbers -se this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6290173/regex-pattern-for-capital-letters-and-numbers-only-with-possible-list